# Open Bootstrap dialog window from Spring MVC BE

Tags: javascript, spring, bootstrap-4

I have a Spring MVC controller and bootstrap page.

When I submit the form and send some payload to this endpoint if some condition is not met I would like to display confirmation window:

API:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/pairs")
    public String addPair(@ModelAttribute StepForm addPairStepForm,
                          Model model) {
    ....... // do some check and trigger modal dialog in FE
    }
```

Bootstrap page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>test</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<main>
        
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="validationModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="validationModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="validationModalLabel">Confirmation</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Pair already exists for the same exchange.
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
                   
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <form id="add_pair_form" class="form-inline" action="#" th:action="@{/pairs}"
                      th:object="${stepForm}"
                      autocomplete="off"
                      method="post">

                    <div class="row g-3 align-items-center mb-1 mt-1">
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <label for="pair" class="form-label">New</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <input id="pair" class="form-control" name="pair" type="text"
                                   placeholder="Pair to be added."
                                   th:field="*{pair}"
                                   required
                                   autofocus>
                        ......................................
                        </div>                            
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mb-1 mt-1">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit_btn">Submit</button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#validationModal">
                        Validate
                    </button>
                </div>
                    
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>       
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

How I can open the modal dialog window when I submit the form and post some payload to Spring BE? I would like to do some validation in BE and if I get error to display dialog window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some mechanism to signal your view that it should display your modal.

As your are using Spring and Thymeleaf, you can, for example, try setting a `boolean` flag, let's say `pairAlreadyExistsWithTheSameExchange`, in your Spring model, in the `addPairs` method, when the appropriate conditions are met:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/pairs")
public String addPair(@ModelAttribute StepForm addPairStepForm,
                      Model model) {
  ....... // do some check and trigger modal dialog in FE
  
  // set the required flag if appropriate
  model.addAttribute("pairAlreadyExistsWithTheSameExchange", true);

  // ...
  return "path to your thymeleaf page";
}
```

Now, you need to modify your view to take into account the new model attribute and display the modal dialog in consequence.

For example, you can include the modal, with the necessary information to make it visible - by applying the `show` `class` and the `display: block` style - if `pairAlreadyExistsWithTheSameExchange` is `true`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>test</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<main>
        
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div th:if="${pairAlreadyExistsWithTheSameExchange}" class="modal fade show" id="validationModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="validationModalLabel" aria-modal="true" role="dialog" style="display: block;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="validationModalLabel">Confirmation</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Pair already exists for the same exchange.
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
                   
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <form id="add_pair_form" class="form-inline" action="#" th:action="@{/pairs}"
                      th:object="${stepForm}"
                      autocomplete="off"
                      method="post">

                    <div class="row g-3 align-items-center mb-1 mt-1">
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <label for="pair" class="form-label">New</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <input id="pair" class="form-control" name="pair" type="text"
                                   placeholder="Pair to be added."
                                   th:field="*{pair}"
                                   required
                                   autofocus>
                        ......................................
                        </div>                            
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mb-1 mt-1">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit_btn">Submit</button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#validationModal">
                        Validate
                    </button>
                </div>
                    
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>       
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Or, alternatively, you can leave the modal as in your original code and include something like the following Javascript code snippet in your HTML page:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" th:if="${pairAlreadyExistsWithTheSameExchange}">
    var validationModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('validationModal'));
    validationModal.show();
</script>
```

As you can see, it gets a reference to the id of the div of your modal dialog window and [shows it via Javascript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#via-javascript).

Probably you can provide a similar information and obtain a similar result by including a request parameter, etcetera, but in my opinion this way is more clear and easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I assume for example you want to validate input with `id="pair"`
You want to check if this entry is empty or not:

```
$( "#add_pair_form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const pairValue = $("#pain").val();

  if(pairValue.trim() == "") {
     // show alert dialogue
    alert('YOUR ERROR MESSAGE');
    return;
  }
  ...

  $.ajax({
    url: "API_URL",
    success: function(result){
      // result is data from response
      ....
    }
  });
});
```

Keep in mind this was an example :)

Comment: How I can send a request to endpoint and display the result without page reload or redirect?

Comment: @user1285928 by using `Ajax`,  ajax handle this problem :)

Comment: can you show me code example please?

Comment: @user1285928 I Improve my above answer

Comment: hm... an you include my code, please?

Comment: @user1285928 I don't understand what is your meaning, can you explain better?